# Woocommerce - Show current category subcategories on sidebar only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been searching for this on the internet and after some hours, haven't find anything that could help me solve this.

I have three main categories, let's say "NIKE", "ADIDAS", "PUMA". And under those categories I have normal subcategories like "T-SHIRTS", "SHOES", "HOODIES"...

What I want to do is when I'm browsing "NIKE" Only show the NIKE'S SUBCATEGORIES on the sidebar. I don't want woocoommerce to show me the other brands as options.

I found that woocommerce have the ability to "Show only current category's subcategories" but when I go to a category that doesn't have children, that widget just dissapears. I would like it to just show the sibling categories instead of dissapearing.

---

I found this: http://www.kablooeystudios.com/woocommerce-sidebar-parents-or-children/ but the code this guy shares, I don't know which is the file I'm supposed to put this code on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can paste codes to your themes functions.php but I m still a bit confuzed why you do need sibling categories there

Comment: @Alice thanks for replying! For example.... I'm browsing NIKE, I see a list of NIKE'S subcategories on my sidebar, like Hoodies, shoes, t-shirts, etc. If I click on "T-Shirts" it will show me all the t-shirt products, but since T-shirts doesn't have a subcategory, the widget will dissaspear. It should still show the other categories :(

Comment: @Alice by the way... this code should not be put on functions.php, if you look at it, it wouldn't make sense... there's no functions or hooks there.

Comment: @JuanBonnett as this code displays the data directly you should place it inside a template file or in your case in a widget. You could write your own widget with that code and it should probably work